# showing a different list when user clicks on category in listview.builder

Tags: flutter

currently i am showing a full list, my list contains questions, I am showing elevated buttons on top which has Chapters list, when user onPressed i want to show a filtered by Chapter list. i tried many things but it's not working.
just like i want to show a product which has a specific category.

my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:quizzy/data_controller.dart';
import 'package:quizzy/models/chapterModel.dart';
import '../models/showQuestion.dart';

class PhyQB extends StatefulWidget {
  const PhyQB({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PhyQB> createState() => _PhyQBState();
}

class _PhyQBState extends State<PhyQB> {
  final DataController controller = Get.put(DataController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      controller.getPhysicsQuestionList();
    });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Physics Question Bank'),
      ),
      body: GetBuilder<DataController>(
        builder: (controller) => controller.PhysicsQuestionList.isEmpty
            ? const Center(
                child: Text(' NO DATA FOUND (: '),
              )
            : Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: controller.PhysicsQuestionList.length,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        reverse: true,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ChapterModel(
                              controller.PhysicsQuestionList[index]);
                        }),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 12,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: controller.PhysicsQuestionList.length,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: showQuestion(
                                controller.PhysicsQuestionList[index]),
                          );
                        }),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

chapter model.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChapterModel extends StatelessWidget {
  ChapterModel(this.ControllerFromCall);

  var ControllerFromCall;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text(ControllerFromCall.ChapterName),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my question model

```
class Question {
  final String QuestionId;
  // To display Question
  final String QuestionText;
  final String? QuestionImageURL;

  // to display Multiple choices (options)

  final String AnswerA;
  final String AnswerB;
  final String AnswerC;
  final String AnswerD;

  // to Display this question was asked in which exam
  final String AskedIn;

  // to display subject and chapter
  final String SubjectName;
  final String ChapterName;

  // To show a detailed explainantion of Correct Answer
  final String CorrectAnswer;

  Question({
    required this.QuestionId,
    required this.QuestionText,
    required this.QuestionImageURL,
    required this.AnswerA,
    required this.AnswerB,
    required this.AnswerC,
    required this.AnswerD,
    required this.AskedIn,
    required this.SubjectName,
    required this.ChapterName,
    required this.CorrectAnswer,
  });
}
```

My data controller.dart file

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:quizzy/models/Question_model.dart';
import 'dart:io';

import 'models/comman_dailog.dart';

class DataController extends GetxController {
  final firebaseInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
  }

 List<Question> PhysicsQuestionList = [];

  Future<void> getPhysicsQuestionList() async {
    PhysicsQuestionList = [];
    try {
      CommanDialog.showLoading();

      final List<Question> physicsloadedQuestions = [];
      var response = await firebaseInstance
          .collection('QuestionList')
          .where('SubjectName', isEqualTo: 'Physics')
          .get();

      if (response.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        response.docs.forEach(
          (result) {
            physicsloadedQuestions.add(Question(
              QuestionId: result.id,
              QuestionText: result['QuestionText'],
              QuestionImageURL: result['QuestionImageURL'],
              AnswerA: result['AnswerA'],
              AnswerB: result['AnswerB'],
              AnswerC: result['AnswerC'],
              AnswerD: result['AnswerD'],
              AskedIn: result['AskedIn'],
              SubjectName: result['SubjectName'],
              ChapterName: result['ChapterName'],
              CorrectAnswer: result['CorrectAnswer'],
            ));
          },
        );
      }

      PhysicsQuestionList.addAll(physicsloadedQuestions);
      update();
      CommanDialog.hideLoading();
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      CommanDialog.hideLoading();
    } catch (error) {
      CommanDialog.hideLoading();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The DataController code also matters.

Comment: i have added dataContoller code

Answer (score 0):

Your `List<Question> PhysicsQuestionList = [];` should be replaced by `RxList<Question> PhysicsQuestionList = List<Question>.empty(growable: true).obs;`

The thing is you need to make your variable observable, please refer to the [Getx State Management docs](https://chornthorn.github.io/getx-docs/state-management/reactive-state-manager/index).